# How can i setup multiple sites within a single ASP.Net project?

Tags: asp.net, css

Sorry if the title isn't really related to my question well enough, I wasn't sure how to word what i'm looking for.

What I am looking for is a way to create sub entities? of a site.

Example:
  We have a site known as 'xyz' and this has a default style, and you would access it via  'www.xyz.com'.

What I want to be able to do is something like  'www.xyz.com/a' -> and this would loadthe same site with a different layout/css.

The differences could be as simple as some css color changes while others could be minor html structure differences.

But i'm afraid i dont know where to start looking to figure this out.

Any guidance would help a lot

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy, you would have seperate *Projects* within your website *Solution*.  Just create a solution and (within Solution Explorer) right click and create a new project.  Take a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817674.aspx).

In terms of the URL usually the accepted method is to set up sub domains like so:

```
http://site1.xyz.com
http://site2.xyz.com
```

Comment: Since this is just for Demoing purposes at this time, I found that I can accomplish my goals using a virtual directory in IIS, which is close to what you suggested just the subsets are not part of my solution, which is fine at this time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having separate sites, why not use `Profile` or another persistence mechanism to decide at run-time which theme to use?

For example:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Theme = Profile.UI.Theme = "Reddish";
}
```

See [Ode to Code](http://odetocode.com/Articles/440.aspx) for a complete Profile example.

Comment: This doesnt allow for the html changes that would take place unfortunately, BUT this does sound useful for something else we are doing, so thank you :)